# What's the difference between DataOutputStream and ObjectOutputStream?

Tags: java, android, sockets

I'm learning about socket programming in Java.  I've seen client/server app examples with some using `DataOutputStream`, and some using `ObjectOutputStream`.

What's the difference between the two?

Is there a performance difference?

Comment: Read [***ObjectOutputStream***](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/ObjectInputStream.html) for a detailed, with example, explanation.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

DataInput/OutputStream performs generally better because its much simpler. It can only read/write primtive types and Strings.

ObjectInput/OutputStream can read/write any object type was well as primitives. It is less efficient but much easier to use if you want to send complex data.

I would assume that the Object*Stream is the best choice until you *know* that its performance is an issue.

Comment: Thanks Peter, exactly the kind of concise answer I was hoping for :-)

Comment: @Peter Lawrey you have mentioned ObjectInput/OutputStream can send complex data. what you mean by complex data? can you please explain

Comment: InputStream and OutputStream are the most generic IO streams you can use and they are the base class of all streams in Java.

Comment: @JaiminPatel While true you often want to write a primitive rather than just bytes.

Answer (score 12):

This might be useful for people still looking for answers several years later... According to my tests on a recent JVM (1.8_51), the `ObjectOutput/InputStream` is surprisingly almost 2x times faster than `DataOutput/InputStream` for reading/writing a huge array of double!

Below are the results for writing 10 million items array (for 1 million the results are the essentially the same). I also included the text format (BufferedWriter/Reader) for the sake of completeness:

```
TestObjectStream written 10000000 items, took: 409ms, or 24449.8778 items/ms, filesize 80390629b
TestDataStream written 10000000 items, took: 727ms, or 13755.1582 items/ms, filesize 80000000b
TestBufferedWriter written 10000000 items, took: 13700ms, or 729.9270 items/ms, filesize 224486395b
```

Reading:

```
TestObjectStream read 10000000 items, took: 250ms, or 40000.0000 items/ms, filesize 80390629b
TestDataStream read 10000000 items, took: 424ms, or 23584.9057 items/ms, filesize 80000000b
TestBufferedWriter read 10000000 items, took: 6298ms, or 1587.8057 items/ms, filesize 224486395b
```

I believe Oracle has heavily optimized the JVM for using `ObjectStream`s in last Java releases, as this is the most common way of writing/reading data (including serialization), and thus is located on the Java performance critical path.

So looks like today there's no much reason anymore to use `DataStream`s. "Don't try to outsmart JVM", just use the most straightforward way, which is `ObjectStream`s :)

Here's the code for the test:

```
class Generator {
    private int seed = 1235436537;
    double generate(int i) {
        seed = (seed + 1235436537) % 936855463;
        return seed / (i + 1.) / 524323.;
    }
}

class Data {
    public final double[] array;
    public Data(final double[] array) {
        this.array = array;
    }
}

class TestObjectStream {
    public void write(File dest, Data data) {
        try (ObjectOutputStream out = new ObjectOutputStream(new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(dest)))) {
            for (int i = 0; i < data.array.length; i++) {
                out.writeDouble(data.array[i]);
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new RuntimeIoException(e);
        }
    }
    public void read(File dest, Data data) {
        try (ObjectInputStream in = new ObjectInputStream(new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(dest)))) {
            for (int i = 0; i < data.array.length; i++) {
                data.array[i] = in.readDouble();
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new RuntimeIoException(e);
        }
    }
}

class TestDataStream {
    public void write(File dest, Data data) {
        try (DataOutputStream out = new DataOutputStream(new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(dest)))) {
            for (int i = 0; i < data.array.length; i++) {
                out.writeDouble(data.array[i]);
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new RuntimeIoException(e);
        }
    }
    public void read(File dest, Data data) {
        try (DataInputStream in = new DataInputStream(new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(dest)))) {
            for (int i = 0; i < data.array.length; i++) {
                data.array[i] = in.readDouble();
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new RuntimeIoException(e);
        }
    }
}

class TestBufferedWriter {
    public void write(File dest, Data data) {
        try (BufferedWriter out = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(dest))) {
            for (int i = 0; i < data.array.length; i++) {
                out.write(Double.toString(data.array[i]));
                out.newLine();
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new RuntimeIoException(e);
        }
    }
    public void read(File dest, Data data) {
        try (BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(dest))) {
            String line = in.readLine();
            int i = 0;
            while (line != null) {
                if(!line.isEmpty()) {
                    data.array[i++] = Double.parseDouble(line);
                }
                line = in.readLine();
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new RuntimeIoException(e);
        }
    }
}

@Test
public void testWrite() throws Exception {
    int N = 10000000;
    double[] array = new double[N];
    Generator gen = new Generator();
    for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        array[i] = gen.generate(i);
    }
    Data data = new Data(array);

    Map<Class, BiConsumer<File, Data>> subjects = new LinkedHashMap<>();
    subjects.put(TestDataStream.class, new TestDataStream()::write);
    subjects.put(TestObjectStream.class, new TestObjectStream()::write);
    subjects.put(TestBufferedWriter.class, new TestBufferedWriter()::write);

    subjects.forEach((aClass, fileDataBiConsumer) -> {

        File f = new File("test." + aClass.getName());

        long start = System.nanoTime();
        fileDataBiConsumer.accept(f, data);
        long took = TimeUnit.NANOSECONDS.toMillis(System.nanoTime() - start);

        System.out.println(aClass.getSimpleName() + " written " + N + " items, took: " + took + "ms, or " + String.format("%.4f", (N / (double)took)) + " items/ms, filesize " + f.length() + "b");
    });
}


@Test
public void testRead() throws Exception {
    int N = 10000000;
    double[] array = new double[N];
    Data data = new Data(array);

    Map<Class, BiConsumer<File, Data>> subjects = new LinkedHashMap<>();
    subjects.put(TestDataStream.class, new TestDataStream()::read);
    subjects.put(TestObjectStream.class, new TestObjectStream()::read);
    subjects.put(TestBufferedWriter.class, new TestBufferedWriter()::read);

    subjects.forEach((aClass, fileDataBiConsumer) -> {
        File f = new File("test." + aClass.getName());

        long start = System.nanoTime();
        fileDataBiConsumer.accept(f, data);
        long took = TimeUnit.NANOSECONDS.toMillis(System.nanoTime() - start);

        System.out.println(aClass.getSimpleName() + " read " + N + " items, took: " + took + "ms, or " + String.format("%.4f", (N / (double)took)) + " items/ms, filesize " + f.length() + "b");
    });
}
```

Comment: Interesting! Thanks for the info.

Comment: Maybe running the TestDataStream after first running TestObjectStream slowed it down. Data stream and Object stream use the same logic for reading/writing to stream. Then why would their runtime be different?

Answer (score 8):

`DataOutputStream` and `ObjectOutputStream`: when handling basic types, there is no difference apart from the header that `ObjectOutputStream` creates.

With the `ObjectOutputStream` class, instances of a class that implements `Serializable` can be written to the output stream, and can be read back with `ObjectInputStream`.

`DataOutputStream` can only handle basic types.

Answer (score 1):

Only objects that implement the `java.io.Serializable` interface can be written to streams using `ObjectOutputStream`.Primitive data types can also be written to the stream using the appropriate methods from DataOutput. Strings can also be written using the writeUTF method. But `DataInputStream` on the other hand  lets an application write **primitive Java data types** to an output stream in a portable way.

[Object OutputStream](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/io/ObjectOutputStream.html)

[Data Input Stream](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/io/DataInputStream.html)

Comment: Incorrect. Primitives can be written to an `ObjectOutputStream`.

Comment: `Only objects that support the java.io.Serializable interface can be written to streams` please see this line from the above javadocs link i provided. The class description says it can be written when the Serializable interface is implemented.I never mentioned primitive types can't be written to this stream

Comment: @sasidhar Then you should consider changing the wording of your answer, because it implies that only `Objects` can be written to the `ObjectOutputStream`. (Which is probably why you have 2 downvotes)